# Symbolic Link Error with MySQL Cluster and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mysql, symbolic-link, cluster

I want to install MySQL Cluster on Ubuntu and I followed this tutorial [Install MySQL Cluster on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://www.mrxuri.com/2013/11/20/install-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts.html).  My management node installed successfully, but I am having a problem in my database node.  According to the tutorial I should create a symbolic link and change directory to mysql.  This is not working for me.

```
ln -s mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.3-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64 mysql
cd mysql
```

When I type command `cd mysql` it is giving me the error:

```
-su: cd: mysql: No such file or directory
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: can you provide the results of `ls -l mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.3-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64 mysql` in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Symlink is incorrect.

My symlink for mysql goes to `"mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.3-"` but the version of mysql-cluster is `mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.5-linux-` (not 7.3.5 vs 7.3.3)